# Can't Remove Kernel Extensions Under Mojave

Tags: crash, mojave, kernel-extensions

After updating to Mojave my system crashes. It can only be started in safe-mode.

According to crash logs from `sysdiagnose`, a particular extension is causing problems:

```
0xffffff811b0f3fa0 : 0xffffff800c9590ce
  Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
    com.coriolis-systems.driver.Snapshot(122.0)[5611248B-6440-3559-9F69-2F249150EA5A]@0xffffff7f8d734000->0xffffff7f8d7aafff
      dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[499E27C9-AC4D-3239-9FC4-754C7699FA76]@0xffffff7f8d704000
```

It seems the extension can be found but not removed

```
$:/Library/Extensions$ kextfind -b com.coriolis-systems.driver.Snapshot
/Library/Extensions/CoriolisSnapshot.kext
$:/Library/Extensions$ kextunload -b /Library/Extensions/CoriolisSnapshot.kext
(kernel) Kext /Library/Extensions/CoriolisSnapshot.kext not found for unload request.
Failed to unload /Library/Extensions/CoriolisSnapshot.kext - (libkern/kext) not found.
```

How do I remove this extension completely? It also shows up under `/Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions` and `/Library//SystemMigration/History/Migration-XXX/QuarantineRoot/Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions/`

For that matter are there any way to just remove all third-party extensions without a fresh install?

-- UPDATE --

After losing patience I just removed the `/Library/Extensions/CoriolisSnapshot.kext` directory after having started in safe-mode. The system booted successfully into Mojave and then opened notification windows indicating several third party extensions were blocked. After allowing one to load the security and privacy pane opened where I was able to check/uncheck other extensions. The Coriolis Systems box was there and I left it unchecked. The system then restarted successfully without any more requests.

Fair warning! This was somewhat risky. Removing system folders can have unintended consequences. The *only* reason I was willing to try was that I made a full disk image backup just prior to installing Mojave.

Comment: try `rm file name` in Terminal

Comment: Simply removing system extensions with `rm` is risky because they may have dependencies. The only reason I tried it was that `kextunload` didn't work and I was prepared with a backup.

Answer (score 5):

As the developer responsible for that KEXT, I'm sorry that it's crashing.  You did the right thing just deleting it; it isn't going to be updated for Mojave (because, frankly, there's no point; what with APFS and the various security changes, I'm afraid iDefrag is now a legacy-only product).

For anyone else seeing this problem, you can boot into Safe Mode by restarting your machine and holding Shift (the key marked ⇧) when you hear the boot chime.  Alternatively, you can boot into Recovery Mode by holding Command (⌘) and R when you hear the chime; if you're in Recovery Mode, you can open Terminal from the "Utilities" menu at the top of the screen.

To delete the KEXT, follow the instructions below:

### From Finder

1. In Finder, choose "Go to Folder…" from the "Go" menu.
2. Enter `/Library/Extensions` into the box that appears.
3. Press "Go" (or hit Return).
4. Drag the CoriolisSnapshot.kext to the Trash (or choose "Move to Trash" from the "File" menu).

### From Terminal

1. Enter `sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/CoriolisSnapshot.kext` at the prompt, and press Return.
2. If prompted, enter your password and press Return.

Comment: I'd like to kindly ask you to add warning to Coriolis' page about iDefrag messing up a newer macOS.
Also instructions on how to remove kexts in the same place would be helpful. Did I understood right, that kexts have to deleted in Recovery or Safe Mode?

Comment: One does *not* have to boot into 'Recovery' or 'Safe Mode' to delete kernel extensions _(kexts)_ from '/Library/Extensions'. _(If a system will not boot, however, then deleting from either the recovery environment or while in 'Safe Mode' will work as well.)_

Comment: In this case the system won’t boot with the extension installed, so you do need to use Safe Mode.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the files inside `Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions/`, open **Terminal** and type `sudo kextcache --clear-staging` and the files will be erased. To make sure they get completely removed, reboot your Mac. Also, this doesn't require you to disable **SIP**.

Answer (score 1):

I found it by myself! Thanks to Alastair to making me going a bit deeper into reasoning why removing physically everything still gave me the error.

Disable SIP!!! <--- ALMOST EVERYTHING YOU NEED TO DO.

It is much more important than trying anything else. I cannot believe Apple made it so mindblowing to use the "evoluted" way, as they put MacOS much more into "children playing games" OSes...

So, my solution is:

- booting into Recovery Mode by holding Command (⌘) and R when you hear the Mac's chime (as previously stated by Alastair); then from the Utils menu choose Terminal and type `csrutil disable`. type `reboot` or reboot by the specific menu.
- If you also need to clean some cache, I found also some few lines useful for Hackintoshes, but by using the same Recovery Mode, you can go here:
  https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/rebuilding-kernel-cache-in-catalina.285643/

Not all commands work (Gatekeeper is useless in Recovery Mode, isn't it?), but I tried some and nothing gone wrong... at least it says that it cannot be done or files are non-existing...

Cross fingers and reboot: works!
Thanks guys, whatever you wrote for anybody lurking around. It saves headaches to many of us!!!

Long live and prosper, Happy Easter.

Seba